# What can i use in eclipse to open *.ucd file?

Tags: eclipse, class-diagram, entities

I recently got a source code I need to analyze. In it, I can find some *.ucd files in the same package where I have model entities.

I guess those *.ucd stand for UML Class Diagram? Is there any tool in eclipse I can use to open those?

Or is there any way I can generate class diagram from entities (classes annotated with @Entity) ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Amateras Modeler](https://github.com/takezoe/amateras-modeler) produces .ucd files for *use case diagrams*. You can also try to open the file in a text editor, if you are lucky then this is an XMI file in which you can find a URL with hints of who developed the tool which was used to produce the file.